# why do we need root and logger in log4j.xml

Tags: log4j

pardon if the question is too trivial. I am completely new to log4j. I have seen that there are two tags  and  tags, which refer to various appenders. 
Say i want to log the information in my code base in a file, send it to my email and print it to console. I want the level set to info. Isnt it enough to have a single  tag which has references to the three appenders ?( file, email and the console) why do we need another  for the same ?

Comment: i mean isnt it enough to have a single root tag ? which has three references to appenders?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It is enough.

In log4j a logger is associated with a package or sometimes with a particular class. Package/class of a logger is defined by the attribute "name". A logger logs messages in its package and also in all the child packages and their classes. The only exception is the root logger that logs messages for the all classes in the application.

A logger also has level and may have one or many appenders (logging destinations) attached to it.

In the next example we have two loggers:

- the root logger that logs messages with level INFO or above in the all packages to the various destinations: console, e-mail and file,
- "com.foo" logger that logs messages with level WARN or above in package "com.foo" and its child packages to the another file.

```xml
<log4j:configuration>
    <!-- Declaration of appenders FILE, MAIL, CONSOLE and ANOTHERFILE -->
    ...
    <!-- -->

    <logger name="com.foo">
        <level value="warn"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ANOTHERFILE" /> 
    </logger>
    <root> 
        <priority value ="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" /> 
        <appender-ref ref="MAIL" />
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" /> 
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

You should [read more](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) about the log4j basics.

Comment: Does root logger also log the messages of "com.foo" classess?

Comment: @mmc18 Yes, definetely. All the messages that are written to appender ANOTHERFILE also written to the root logger's appenders.

Comment: Just an additional note, you can prevent messages sent to ANOTHERFILE from being sent to the root logger by setting the additivity property of the logger to false.  Think of it like an exception, bubbling up from a lower level to the top (root).  addivity is the "catch" without a "throw"

Comment: how and where do you reference/use the 'logger name="com.foo"'? thank you.

Comment: Just a question , can we set root logger  error and package level logging to info ?

Comment: @NilayTiwari Yes, the settings on the package level just override the settings of the root logger.